# How to build Restful API without using frontend javascript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have been searching all over for a tutorial that could make a RESTFul API without using any frontend javascript to no avail. I am very new to Javascript/ web-development and have been doing many tutorials and mini projects to get myself acquainted with it.

This is a test for a job at a startup as they looking for an entry level developer. Their requirements are much different as they want me to use their in house build APIs.

What I am looking for is some help on how to get started building a RESTful API using node.js, express, Mongo and without using any frontend javascript. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need frontend javascript to build a Restful API.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript to build a RESTful API... unless you are referring to not using an AJAX requests to pull the RESTful data? Because the RESTful API itself would be built using some server side technology (i.e. node, django, asp, etc.) then you can call it with some type of templating engine or javascript or pure html depending on what you used.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me.   A restful API is implemented by a server.  Frontend Javascript might optionally be one of the users of such an API, but has nothing to do with the implementation of the API.  Can you explain why you think you need help avoiding frontend javascript?

Comment: Again, I am new to this. My apologies. Are there any tutorials out there that exclude frontend javascript to build a RESTFul API Todo list?

Comment: Rather than looking for a tutorial that does not use JavaScript, you should look for a tutorial that uses Node & Mongo, build your API, then worry about how you are going to display your data.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations for tutorials usually don't make good questions for Stack Overflow, but you might want to take a look at the following books. They helped me out quite a bit when getting started with Node:

[Express Web Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849696543)

[Advanced Express Web Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783282495)

[RESTful Web API Design with Node.js](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783985860)

As others have commented, a **RE**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer API is implemented server-side. You could consume such an API from the client-side using JavaScript, but not build one on the client-side.

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a very popular web framework for Node, and you can certainly use it to build APIs, but you might also take a look at [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/). Hope that helps you out.